# Spring Starter Project - 'Import Getting Started Content' error

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

When creating a new spring starter project, as I go to finish building the project I seem to get one of two errors, both relating to importing the getting started content. The dependencies I am adding in the sql dependencies, JDBC and H2.

[image: Import Getting Started Content Error]

or

[image: Import Getting Started Content Error]

I have maven installed but this is my first time using spring so I have no idea what I'm doing and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does your eclipse know of Maven existence? There should be some configuration settings to specify the maven home dir

Comment: @Funtik I'm pretty sure eclipse knows of it, I've created and used maven projects in eclipse before anyway!